# Ionic view not getting update frequently for every changes of component property update

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, angular2-services, ionic4

I'm using ionic 3. I have an issue on updating stock data on view. I can get update frequently on my component and I can see in my console regarding the changes but not updating that changes in my view. But my view getting update rare case. If 10 update happens in component means 1 update getting in my view.
I have written code as below,
Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MarketService{
fncallback:any;
stocks: string[][];
  constructor( ) {
    this.initStocks();
    this.subscribeStocks();
  }
subscribeStocks() {
        this.lsClient = new LightstreamerClient("http://localhost:8080", "WBSTOCKLIST_REMOTE");
        this.lsClient.connectionSharing.enableSharing("WBCommonConnection", "ATTACH", "CREATE");
        this.lsClient.connect();
        this.subscription = new Subscription("MERGE", this.itemNames, this.fieldNames);
        this.subscription.setDataAdapter("WBQUOTE_ADAPTER");
        this.subscription.addListener({
            onItemUpdate: (updateObject) => {
                var itemName = updateObject.getItemName();
                updateObject.forEachChangedField((fieldName, fieldPos, val) => {
                      var itemIndex = this.itemNames.indexOf(itemName);
                      var fieldIndex = this.fieldNames.indexOf(fieldName);
                      console.assert(fieldIndex != -1);
                      console.assert(itemIndex != -1);
                      this.stocks[itemName][fieldName] = val;
                });
                this.fncallback(this.stocks);
            }
        });
        this.lsClient.subscribe(this.subscription);
    }
    setcallback(fn){
      this.fncallback = fn;
    } 
}
```

My component code looks like,

```
export class MarketPage {
baserates:any;
  constructor(public marketService: MarketService) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log( 'ionViewDidLoad MatketPage' );
        this.marketService.setcallback((data)=>{
          this.baserates = data;
          console.log(this.baserates); //This update happens frequently
         });
    }

}
```

My view looks like,

```
<ion-row class="light-border-btm align-items"  *ngIf="baserates">
      <ion-col col-3>Gold</ion-col>
      <ion-col col-3>{{ baserates['SPOT-GOLD']['bid'] }}</ion-col>
      <ion-col col-3>{{ baserates['SPOT-GOLD']['ask'] }}</ion-col>
      <ion-col col-3>H:{{ baserates['SPOT-GOLD']['high'] }}<br/>L:{{ baserates['SPOT-GOLD']['low'] }}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

But my view not getting update frequently as getting update in component baserates field.
Could you please help anyone. I have used Lightstreamer for update rates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ChangeDetectorRef for update UI.

Once you receive response from API in constructor add dependance

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and then once you receive response just call

> this.cd.markForCheck();